# How to show that increasing r.v. imply stochastic dominance?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

How can one prove the following statement:

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $X(\omega) \geqslant Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ then $\mathbb P(X>x) \geqslant \mathbb P(Y>x)$ ?

I saw this in a textbook and wondered why is it true? I have some intuition (as if $Y>x$ then $X>x$ since $X>Y$, likewise if $X>x$ then $Y$ is not necessarily greater than $x$).

I'd just want to see an algebraic proof :o

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that $\mathbb P(X>x)\geqslant \mathbb P(Y>x)$, right?

Comment: yes, opps.. I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed $x\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$\{\omega: Y(\omega) > x\}\subset\{\omega: X(\omega)>x\}, $$
since $Y(\omega)>x$ implies $X(\omega)\geqslant Y(\omega)>x$. Hence
$$\mathbb P\{\omega: Y(\omega) > x\}\leqslant \mathbb P\{\omega: X(\omega)>x\}$$
by monotonicity of probability measures.

Comment: yea, looks easier than I thought it did!
Thank you!
p.s. I would vote you up, but it says I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: No worries, welcome to MSE!