# How can I prove if $Y\leq X$ then $E[Y]\leq E[X]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $Y\leq X$ always holds, then $E[Y]\leq E[X]$. How can I prove this (formally)? Also, can the equality happen if we know that $Y=X$ does not always hold? (i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are not exactly the same)

Comment: How about showing that $E[X-Y]\geq 0$?

Comment: If you replace $E$ by $\int$, it will become very obvious.

Comment: You need to assume those expected values exist.  Then since $E$ corresponds to integration with respect to a probability measure, it is obvious.
Equality will occur iff $X = Y$ almost surely, i.e.  $P(X=Y) = 1$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113531/how-to-show-that-increasing-r-v-imply-stochastic-dominance/1113560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $X,Y$ real valued with $Y(\omega)\leq X(\omega)\Leftrightarrow0\leq X-Y$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$ and $\mathbf{E}(X),\mathbf{E}(Y)$ exists, we set as mentioned in the comments

$$
Z=X-Y\geq0
$$

Now we just plug in and get
$$
\mathbf{E}(Z)=\mathbf{E}(X-Y)=\mathbf{E}(X)-\mathbf{E}(Y)=\int_{\Omega}Z\:dP\geq\int_{\Omega}0\:dP=0\Leftrightarrow\mathbf{E}(X)\geq\mathbf{E}(Y)
$$
Further we do also have equality of
$$
\mathbf{E}(X)=\mathbf{E}(Y)
$$
if for example $Y=X$ almost everywhere (so they just not equal on a nullset wrt to $P$). This is a sufficient condition.

Comment: What does P denote?

Comment: I almost see what's happening here. But are we assuming that the variables are continuous? I'm a bit confused

Comment: @user798275 usually you have the triplet $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$ with, in your case, $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbf{P}$ denotes the measure which defines the expectation of X. We do not assume anything else but your inequality and the existence of the expectations, so especially we do not assume any continuity.